# Where is Kindle 3's OS / factory-reset data and can I access it?

Tags: kindle

I have a Kindle Keyboard (K3gb) with a broken screen, so even though it's otherwise working, I can only do anything with it by connecting it to a PC via USB. When connected to a PC, you can see a data partition containing ebooks etc. and some system files, but nothing that looks like OS or software files.

Where exactly is the OS and factory-reset data, and is there a way to access it in order to see the content? Also, is it possible to write into it? I talked with Amazon's Kindle support, and they insisted that the OS cannot be changed, but they refused to confirm whether it's on read-only memory or something similar.

The reason I'm asking is that I'm about to take my device into a shop for a screen replacement, which they refuse to perform in my presence, so I have some security concerns. I've already made a backup image of the "data" partition and wiped it with a full factory reset, but I'm concerned with the possibility of malware being installed while in the lab.

In short,

1. Is it possible for one to access and edit the OS / factory-reset data of the Kindle? If not (as Amazon claims), why not?
2. How can I read (without making changes) the OS / factory-reset data? Do I need to jailbreak the device first, and if so, is it possible to do so via PC connection? (I've come across the [Yifan Lu et al. jailbreak](https://yifan.lu/p/kindle-jailbreak/), but it requires navigating to Settings and updating, which I can't do with a broken screen.)

I'm asking the 2nd question because I thought that if I can read and make an image of the data in question, I could do it again after the repair and compare the two copies to detect any tampering.

**P.S.**
I know that the probability of such tampering is actually small, but the question of how to access the data is still valid, so I'd rather focus on that.

Comment: They aren’t going to tamper with your device. The Kindle OS is proprietary and I’ve never heard of someone having malware on one. You could maybe download a bad app on a Kindle Fire. The reason they aren’t going to change the screen in front of you is because they have other work to do too. They might repair other devices before they get to yours. And their lab space is for employees, not for people to watch them like a hawk. If they were untrustworthy, they wouldn’t keep business coming in. In my opinion you’re being overly paranoid. Let them do their job, so you can get back to reading.

Comment: @DrZoo, I don't see how the OS being proprietary is relevant. Btw, they will actually fix it while I wait; I'm not allowed into the lab for insurance reasons (doesn't cover customers). Also, they are a small London shop, so their business does not really depend on brand/reputation building. In fact, if I were a black-hat hacker, a device-repair shop is exactly the kind of front I would be setting up. I'm not saying it's very likely, but your absolute trust is not really justifiable.

Comment: @DrZoo: Incidentally, I've been called paranoid about many things before, but after the Snowden revelations, it was clear that my most paranoid fears had not been paranoid enough!

Comment: Could you not replace the screen yourself? Unless it is soldered (which is highly unlikely), it should just be a matter of popping the case, removing a ribbon cable from the old screen, swap out the screen, insert the new screen, insert ribbon cable & close case.